# Como selecionar chave estrangeira mais utilizada?

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Eu gostaria de fazer um `SELECT` onde selecionaria a chave estrangeira(*idTema*) **mais utilizada**

**Exemplo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que no *exemplo acima* seria **1**

Como seria esse `SELECT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor forma de construir o select mas acho que resolve.

```
SELECT idTema FROM nome.tabela GROUP BY idTema ORDER BY count(idTema) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que agrupar pelo `idTema`, ordenar pela quantidade de forma decrescente e limitar em 1 registro:

```
SELECT a.`idTema`, COUNT(*) qtde
FROM nome_da_tabela a
GROUP BY a.`idTema`
ORDER BY qtde DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Veja mais sobre `GROUP BY` [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Comment: Mas aí você ta filtrando sempre o 1, certo? E se o idTema mais utilizado for outro id e não 1. Queria algo geral, entende?

Comment: Não estou limitando o `idTema = 1` e sim limitando a quantidade de linhas que será retornada. Esse `SELECT` funciona pro geral.

Comment: Entendi, irei testar.